# MKNetworkKit: how to clear authentication related caching

Tags: ios, authentication, cookies, basic-authentication, mknetworkkit

Summary of problem: I am using `MKNetworkKit` and use Basic Auth to authenticate myself against a REST server. I am no expert on the detail setup on the server side. All I know is that it will take a Basic Auth without SSL.

If I authenticate myself with a valid user/password, and if I do so 2nd time with some bogus input, it will still succeed. I read documentation and tried to do this:

```
[op setCredentialPersistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
```

it doesnt work. But if i do this:

```
[op setCredentialPersistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
[op addHeader:@"Cookie" withValue:@""];   // a hunch I tried
```

then it seemed to work. It is as if some cookie is always being passed and the server accepts it without even checking the authorization header. I have done a few test where I will provide things in this order (good, bogus, good), and (bogus, good, bogus), and it seemed to be working as expected.

Now, could someone point out if this is not how things should work, that there must be a bug somewhere, either `MKNetworkKit`, or the server side? If I set `NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone`, then why would adding that Cookie header will make it work?? it must have overwritten the thing it would have sent and caused the wrong behavior, and thus "fixed" it.

Comment: Probably the server adds a session cookie after the authentication. Try to log `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]` before the request and after you receive the response.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol, clients often use cookies to provide persistent storage of data across URL requests. The URL loading system provides interfaces to create and manage cookies, to send cookies as part of an HTTP request, and to receive cookies when interpreting a web server’s response.
OS X and iOS provide the NSHTTPCookieStorage class, which in turn provides the interface for managing a collection of NSHTTPCookie objects. In OS X, cookie storage is shared across all apps; in iOS, cookie storage is per-app.(check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) As stated by Moxy Try to log [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies].I was facing the same issue and reason was cookies were used and maintained by the server.As redirection was taking place whenever i logged in using the credentials i checked the request and response in

- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection*)inConnection
           willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest*)inRequest
          redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse*)inRedirectResponse

And cookies were maintained in the headers.The only thing you can do is sending a random cookie for a new session